How to prove Exercise 8.2.6 from Analysis 1 Terence Tao
I have been stuck a while on the following exercise of Analysis 1 from Terence Tao:
Exercise 8.2.6 Let $\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n$ be a series which is conditionally convergent, but not absolutely convergent. Show that there exists a bijection $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ such that $\sum^\infty_{m=0}a_{f(m)}$ diverges to $+\infty$, or more precisely that $$\liminf_{N\to \infty}\sum^\infty_{m=N}a_{f(m)}=\limsup_{N\to \infty}\sum^\infty_{m=N}a_{f(m)}=+\infty$$ (Of course, a similar statement holds with $+\infty$ replaced by $-\infty$)
I tried a few different approaches but they seemed all pretty long and contained a lot of additional lemmas to prove so maybe I am missing some key insight.
I would thus really appreciate if someone could help out with some clues on how to prove it or provide a proof.
Thank you in advance!
Small sidenote: Somebody tried asking this question in the past but failed to get an answer due to poor formatting and context in his question. So this is not a duplicate.

Welcome. If you want to compare with this and similar results, search for "Riemann's rearrangement theorem"

The hint is that you want to note the positive and negative components of the series respectively diverge, so you can reorder and use them to achieve any series sum you desire
